# Add additional element to array

Tags: php, arrays

If I have an array `$MovieDetails = array();` and it is populated by the query below with a foreach loop (5 elements; `id, movie_year, genre, image, movie_name`), how do I add another element (`movie_rating`) to the end of the array

```
$AllMovies = $con ->query
("
    SELECT id, movie_year, genre, image, movie_name FROM movies; 
");

 while($row = $AllMovies->fetch_object())  {
        $MovieDetails[] = $row;
    }
```

Comment: add it to $row with $row['movie_rating'] before you add it to movieDetails

Comment: You could also make it easier to add it later, by changing it to `$MovieDetails[$row['id']] = $row;`. Then if you know the movie id, you can do `$MovieDetails[$id]['movie_rating'] = $rating;`

Comment: You're fetching the results as an `StdClass` object. You'll need to change to `fetch_array()` in order to let the posted answers work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add movie rating into `$row`.

If you work with that as object, it's `$row->movie_rating = 1.5`

```
while($row = $AllMovies->fetch_object())  {
    $row->movie_rating = 1.5;
    $MovieDetails[] = $row;
}
```

If you work with that as array, use `fetch_assoc()` and `$row['movie_rating'] = 1.5`

```
while($row = $AllMovies->fetch_assoc())  {
    $row['movie_rating'] = 1.5;
    $MovieDetails[] = $row;
}
```

Comment: I get back error ` Cannot use object of type stdClass as array`

Comment: should be `fetch_array()`

Comment: @McNoodles: If you work with that as object, there should be `$row->movie_rating = 1.5`. If you want array, change `fetch_object` for `fetch_array`.

Comment: @panther you should reflect this in your answer because your answer is incorrect at this point...

Answer (score 1):

This way your row is an object

```
$AllMovies = $con->query("SELECT id, movie_year, genre, image, movie_name FROM movies;");
while($row = $AllMovies->fetch_object())  {
   $row->movie_rating = 'movieRating'; 
   $MovieDetails[] = $row;
}
```

If you want each row to be array, you should do:

```
while($row = $AllMovies->fetch_array())  {
   $row['movie_rating'] = 'movieRating'; 
   $MovieDetails[] = $row;
}
```

Comment: should be `fetch_array()`

Answer (score 0):

```
$MovieDetails['movie_rating'] = $movie_rating;
```